# two private endpoints with one private dns zone

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-backup-vault

I would like advice on the following:

I have hub and spoke architecture with one hub and one spoke.  I have Private DNS zones deployed in Hub subscription. In Spoke subscription I have two backup Recovery Services Vaults which I need to use with private endpoints.

It seems that this statement from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns applies here:

*Existing Private DNS Zones tied to a single service should not be associated with two different Private Endpoints as it will not be possible to properly resolve two different A-Records that point to the same service. However, Private DNS Zones tied to multiple services would not face this resolution constraint.*

Currently I have created two private endpoints, and linked them to the same Private DNS zone:

[image]

It seems to me that the DNS resolution should work fine since I have different A records in the zone.

Thanks for any tips.
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Created two backup Recovery Services Vaults with private endpoint like below:

[image]

If you have different A records in the Private DNS zone for each backup Recovery Services Vault, created two private endpoints in your spoke subscription and linked them to the same Private DNS zone in your hub subscription. Each private endpoint is associated with a different backup Recovery Services Vault. The DNS resolution should work correctly.

[image]

`A` records are distinct and pointing to different services there won't be any conflict when the DNS is resolved. Each private endpoint will resolve to its respective backup Recovery Services Vault using the unique A record in the Private DNS zone.

***In your private endpoints -> DNS configuration -> Add configuration -> select your hub subscription and add your hub private dns zone like below:***

[image]

You can the check DNS Resolution with spoke subscription. Verify that the resolved IP addresses correspond to expected endpoints like below:

[image]